How to change redirect url for externalbrowser authentication with snowflake
I want to connect to snowflake from python library like snowpark or dbt using externalbrowser as authenticator to use SSO. After successful SSO the redirect URL is using localhost and a random port.
Is there a way to configure this redirect URL?
Specifying the port would be helpful for automation purposes and specifying the host if running it on another machine like (vscode server).

use authenticator: externalbrowser instead of password. It will open default browser where you can login with user name password.  It will work till end of session.

When you use externalbrowser as the authentication method, it requires the user to interact with a pop-up browser to enter their credentials. I'm not clear how you would go about automating that on a remote machine when you won't be able to see that browser.
In any case, based on the code here, you can try using the environment variables SF_AUTH_SOCKET_ADDR and SF_AUTH_SOCKET_PORT to pass the hostname/IP and the port respectively.
